# Easiest way to replace mortar around door?

Tags: repair, concrete, doors, stone

I have a stone house and some of the mortar around one of my door frames has completely eroded away, there are big gaps and I can now see the screws that once screwed into the mortar too hold the door frame in place. What is the easiest way to replace this vertical cement? (Gaps are about 4 inches high, 2 inches wide and 4 inches deep)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A couple of pictures would really help us understand what you're against. If you can't post the pictures, post URLs to them and someone will be along to edit them into the question.